# 404 Not Found on clicking submit button - Servlet not working

Tags: java, forms, servlets

I am a beginner in Servlets so, trying to make a form and display the submitted data by clicking on the submit button. But for now, I have just printed "Welcome to Register form" but I am getting a 404 error not found.

I have tried several URLs in the action attribute of the HTML form:

But none of them resolved it.

**RegisterServlet.java**

```
package com. practice;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Started ..............");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        out.println("<h2> Welcome to Register form </h2>");   // This is the line which needs to get printed
    }

}
```

**index.html  (form layout)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Servlet Form</title>
</head>

<style>

    body{
        background-color: bisque;
    }

    button{
        background-color: blue;
        color: aliceblue;
        padding: 11px 30px;
        border-radius: 10%;
        font-style: oblique;
        font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: medium;
    }

    .container{
        width: 40%;
        border: 5px solid black;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #myform table tr td input{
        font-size: 20px;
    }

</style>

<body>

<div class = "container">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-style: italic">Welcome</h1>

<!--     post method is more secure than get method-->
    <form id="myform" action="RegisterServlet" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>

                <td>Enter Your Full name</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Enter Your Email-ID</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter Your Email-ID"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Enter Your Password</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="user_pass" placeholder="Enter Your Password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Re-Enter Your Password</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="user_pass" placeholder="Enter Your Password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Select Gender</td>
                <td> <input type="radio" name="user_gender" value="male" placeholder="Enter Your Gender">Male &nbsp; &nbsp;  <input type="radio" name="user_gender" value="female" placeholder="Enter Your Gender">Female</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Select Course</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="user_course">
                        <option value="java">JAVA</option>
                        <option value="android">Android Development</option>
                        <option value="web">Web Development</option>
                        <option value="ml">Machine Learning</option>
                        <option value="iot">IOT</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right"> <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="checked"> </td>
                <td> <h3>  Please Agree to the Terms and Conditions </h3> </td>


            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="button">SUBMIT</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="button">RESET</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.practice.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Servlet Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>Hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```